# How to install Asterisk config files?

Tags: apt, 20.04, official-repositories, asterisk

I have installed Asterisk using the `sudo apt-get install asterisk` command, but when I run `asterisk -r` I see the `Unable to open specified master config file '/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf'`, which means that config files were not installed. Is there a way to install them from the official repositories without having to build Asterisk from source code?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Use `ls /etc/asterisk | grep "asterisk.conf"` to check if the file exists (if you see non-empty output, then it exists). If not, you may be able to create an empty one with `sudo touch /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or the problem is that Asterisk is installed as root (using sudo - which is the right way) so you also need elevated rights when editing the configuration file.

Did you check if the master config file exists (using something like `/etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf`) ?

Comment: Yes, this was the case in deed. Thank you very much for your advice. I had to try running Asterisk using 'sudo' before posting this question in the first place.